# How exactly do I extend an openzeppelin contract (ERC721) with their extensions?

Tags: erc-721, openzeppelin-contracts

So I know that in the past there used to be an ERC721Full.sol inside the token directory of openzeppelin but now it seems that they have added an extensions folder that I just can't seem to understand. I want and URI storage `_setTokenURI()` for my NFTs and the Enumerable extension so I can access my `totalSupply()` but I have not been able to find anywhere a good answer. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You just can use multiple inheritance. Inheriting from multiple base classes can be tricky, you have to fulfill each base class' method requirements. A simple example is in the Solidity [docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.5/contracts.html#function-overriding). Basically you'll override virtual methods of base classes, and you have to specify which base class you're overriding. Alternatively you may use Openzeppelin's [ERC721PresetMinterPauserAutoId](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC721/presets/ERC721PresetMinterPauserAutoId.sol) class, this may satisfy ERC721Full you've mentioned.

Here is a little bit detailed example, if you want to mix it with other base contracts.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721Burnable.sol";
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721Enumerable.sol";
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721Pausable.sol";

contract TestContract is ERC721Burnable, ERC721Enumerable, ERC721Pausable {
    constructor() 
    ERC721("Test Nft", "TNFT")
    {
    }
    
    /**
     * override(ERC721, ERC721Enumerable, ERC721Pausable) 
     * here you're overriding _beforeTokenTransfer method of
     * three Base classes namely ERC721, ERC721Enumerable, ERC721Pausable
     * */
    function _beforeTokenTransfer(
        address from,
        address to,
        uint256 tokenId
    ) internal
      override(ERC721, ERC721Enumerable, ERC721Pausable) {
        super._beforeTokenTransfer(from, to, tokenId);
    }
    
    /**
     * override(ERC721, ERC721Enumerable) -> here you're specifying only two base classes ERC721, ERC721Enumerable
     * */
    function supportsInterface(bytes4 interfaceId)
        public
        view
        override(ERC721, ERC721Enumerable)
        returns (bool)
    {
        return super.supportsInterface(interfaceId);
    }
}
```